# Title disappears when editing a particular question

Tags: bug, questions, editing

I made a small edit to [Missing "Visibility" option on Lollipop Calendar](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/88554/1465) and hit Submit, and got an error due to there being no title.  Upon refreshing the page and hitting Edit again, I noticed that the title box was clear rather than retaining the original title.

I haven't encountered this with any other question.

Comment: looks like something went wrong when recording this post's initial revision history records, the first one that shows up is an edit -> http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/88554/revisions

Comment: actually the original revision was deleted since the screenshot contained op's email address. So this is a bug.